# cakePHP 1.3 routes and named params

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, router, named

I had this kind of routes that used to work on cakePHP 1.2

`Router::connect('/mycategory/my-region', array('controller'=>'search',                    'action'=>'properties''named'=>array('region'=>01)));`

How can I accomplish the same in cake 1.3

thanks

Comment: I ended up coding the following 

in routes
 Router::connect('/mycategory/my-region', array('controller'=>'search', 'action'=>'properties',"region"=>01));</code>

in the controller
$this->params['named']['region'] = $this->params['region'];

if there's a better approach let me know

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `my-region` always equals to `01`, then your solution is as good as any other I guess. If however you'd like to be able to have several different regions, then I would suggest something like the following route:

```
Router::connect('/mycategory/:my_region', 
    array('controller' => 'search', 'action' => 'properties'),
    array('pass' => array('my_region'), 'my_region' => '[\#a-zA-Z0-9_-]+')
);
```

And so you can get the value of `my-region`in your controller like so:

```
function properties($my_region = NULL) {
    $regions = array('my-region' => '01');
    $id = $regions[$my_region];
}
```

The controller part can be greatly improved, with if/switch statements. Just wanted to give a very basic example.

**Edit**: And then, build your links like so:

```
<?php echo $this->ExHtml->link(
    'My Region',
    array('controller' => 'search', 'action' => 'properties', 'my_region' => 'my-region')
); ?>
```

which should automagically output:
    `<a href="/mycategory/my-region">My Region</a>`

Comment: thanks man!  with my old route all links were synchronized with my mapping, will this example do the same? or cake generated links will still point to the controller name instead.   thanks

Comment: well, you might have to rewrite all your old links if you didn't fully use the routing capabilities before. I edited my answer to provide an example. The router really is wonderful and powerful, you should really try to use it at its maximum!